# Extracting a substring to the last-nth delimiter C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying in C++ to find

1. the most performant
2. the most elegant

code that takes a string and an integer and for a given delimiter, let's say ".", results to the nth from the last substring.

Example
Input:

string "a.b.c.d.e" and delimFromEndLevel = 1 => string "a.b.c.d"

string "a.b.c.d.e" and delimFromEndLevel = 2 => string "a.b.c"

etc.

Starting point is the following code:

```
void elaborateParent( const std::string& input, unsigned int levels )
{
    std::size_t cutOffIndex = std::string::npos;
    while (levels > 0)
    {
        cutOffIndex = input.rfind('.', cutOffIndex);
        if (cutOffIndex == std::string::npos)
            std::cout << "Not enough levels to go up!" << std::endl; 
        levels--;
        if (levels>0)
        {
            if (cutOffIndex>0)
                cutOffIndex--;
            else
                std::cout << "Not enough levels to go up!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::string result = input.substr(0, cutOffIndex);
    std::cout << "Elaboration parent result: '" << result << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If the code you have works, and you are only looking to improve it, I think that it would be more on-topic on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: And what does not work?

Comment: I would replace `std::cout` by `throw`/`return` (`std::string_view`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating things :)

Just do:

```
std::string elaborateParent( const std::string& input, unsigned int levels )
{
  auto result = input;
  for(; levels != -1; --levels) {
    result.erase(result.find_last_of('.'));
  }
  return result;
}
```

**And I doubt you get better performance than this!**